# Filter based upon the li text and show ul if matched

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I have an array which can be dynamic array, in my html page there will be multiple `ul` with `li` elements. I want to search each `li` of an `ul` element, if the li text is present in my array then show ul else hide that particular ul.

```js
$(function() {

  var filter_array = ['item2', 'item3', 'item28'];

  $('ul li').each(function() {

    var jThis = $(this);
    var current_ul = jThis.attr('data-currentul');
    var current_text = jThis.text();

    if ($.inArray(current_text, filter_array)) {
      console.log("CurrentUL:" + current_ul + " current_text:" + current_text + " ISpresent : Yes");
      $('.ul' + current_ul).show();
    } else {
      console.log("CurrentUL:" + current_ul + " current_text:" + current_text + " ISpresent : No");
      $('.ul' + current_ul).hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="category1" class="ul1">
  <li data-currentul="1">item1</li>
  <li data-currentul="1">item2</li>
  <li data-currentul="1">item3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul2">
  <li data-currentul="2">item27</li>
  <li data-currentul="2">item28</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul3">
  <li data-currentul="3">item29</li>
  <li data-currentul="3">item30</li>
</ul>
```

Expected Output :

```
item1
item2
item3
item27
item28
```

Please refer jsfiddle code for the same : [JSFiddleCode](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/388105/)

Comment: actually you compare li values and try to hide ul ? if out 3 li if one is not match they that ul should be hide ?

Comment: out of 3 if any matched then that ul should be displayed @Affan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) return `-1` if index of element is not found.

Additionally, You can use DOM relation to target the `UL`elements to show instead of using ID selector

```js
$(function() {

  var filter_array = ['item2', 'item3', 'item28'];
  var ul = $('ul');
  //Start Hidden
  ul.hide();

  //filter UL element 
  ul.filter(function() {
    //Get LI elements matching the criteria
    var liHavingText = $(this).find('li').filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), filter_array) > -1; //Compare with index
    });

    return liHavingText.length > 0;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="category1" class="ul1">
  <li data-currentul="1">item1</li>
  <li data-currentul="1">item2</li>
  <li data-currentul="1">item3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul2">
  <li data-currentul="2">item27</li>
  <li data-currentul="2">item28</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul3">
  <li data-currentul="3">item29</li>
  <li data-currentul="3">item30</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array items and check for each `li` if its text matches the array item like:

```
var filter_array = ['item2','item3','item28'];

filter_array.forEach(text => {
    $('li').each(function(index, elem){
        if($(elem).text().trim() == text) {
            $(elem).parent().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Working [jsBin here](https://jsbin.com/buyiviyiwa/1/edit?js,output)

```js
$(function(){
  
  var filter_array = ['item2','item3','item28'];
  
  filter_array.forEach(text => {
    $('li').each(function(index, elem){
      if($(elem).text().trim() == text) {
        $(elem).parent().show();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
ul {display: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul id="category1" class="ul1">
    <li data-currentul="1">item1</li>
    <li data-currentul="1">item2</li>
    <li data-currentul="1">item3</li>
</ul>
<ul  class="ul2">
    <li data-currentul="2">item27</li>
    <li data-currentul="2">item28</li>
</ul>
<ul  class="ul3">
    <li data-currentul="3">item29</li>
    <li data-currentul="3">item30</li>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```